# Jetty Annotation Timeout Reason

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, annotations, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am tying to run my web application with maven jetty plugin. But after some time at startup, it gives the error:

```
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
2014-08-10 17:39:45.840:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.2.v20140723
2014-08-10 17:40:54.961:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@1e2c8{/asd,file:/C:/dev/project/hope/target/asd-1.0/,STARTING}{C:\dev\project\hope\target\asd-1.0.war}
java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
```

I am using spring mvc with annotations and I think there is a problem about it.

When I try to run it over eclipse jetty plugin, it starts succesfully, but with maven plugin, it gives the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've got the same error and to fix it, you should add to your start script (start.ini) the following:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=120
```

120 is for two minutes of annotation scanning in case that you need a higher value, just set it to the propper one.

Comment: how come some small project spend more time, and larger one without the -D still works? what exactly jetty is trying to do there?

Comment: Sometimes the machine takes longer, high cpu usage because other OS processes or too many classes to parse.

Comment: You can reduce scanning jars to improve load speed, see my answer

Answer (score 7):

It is useless to scan all dependent jars, you can make the scanning pattern more restrictive to only match certain jars:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.8.v20150217</version>
  <configuration>
    <webAppConfig>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
      <webInfIncludeJarPattern>.*/foo-[^/]*\.jar$|.*/classes/.*</webInfIncludeJarPattern>
    </webAppConfig>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See `webInfIncludeJarPattern` doc for more details:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp

Comment: I don't understand what pattern I could use. How can I determine what jar/classes are needed. Somehow if maven put these jars in /lib they are needed. Few attempt to use this configuration lead to "ClassNotFoundException". any hint ?

Comment: I would start with a pattern that matches nothing, like the word "none", and see if the application works without scanning. But if you're getting ClassNotFoundException, then take a look at the class name in the exception and try to identify which JAR file it comes from, then enable scanning for that JAR.

Answer (score 5):

One more (in my opinion) convinient way is to set this property using a jetty.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure>
    <Call name="setProperty" class="java.lang.System">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait</Arg>
        <Arg>120</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

This way you can omit the commandline args

Comment: And how do i tell the plugin to use this jetty.xml?

Comment: @NathanBubna i think it looks in the current directory where you're running it, but im not sure. Best is to google it

Comment: @NathanBubna if you use Maven for your project then you could add "jetty.xml" file while configure jetty plugin in your pom.xml using <jettyXml> (read here https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html)

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is adding the system property in pom.xml

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#setting-system-properties

Answer (score 0):

This message means scanning annotation took time more than its being configured thus timeout so this can be fixed either by increasing the timeout period (Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=120) or by deleting the tmp / webapp-tmp from target which reduces its scan time.

Answer (score -4):

The property (-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=120) can be added to start.ini so it works for all the webapps in your app base.

Comment: Same above, look up!

Comment: My intention is to make it explicit on about the configuration file - start.ini. It is not obvious in the accepted answer.