# mvn jetty run timout scanning annotations

Tags: maven, annotations, jetty

I have a problem here.each time when I run the mvn jetty:run i will get the below error. It is something with the annotations and I figured out that in order to fix this, I need to run this...

```
mvn jetty:run -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=120
```

But still it does not solve my problem and I still get the below error. Can anyone help me?

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@34cf294c{/vedc-
web,[file:///D:/VEDC-TEST/vedc-web/src/main/webapp/, jar:file:///C:/Users/Saufi/
.m2/repository/org/webjars/Eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.15.35/Eonasdan-bo
otstrap-datetimepicker-4.15.35.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/Sau
fi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6.jar!/META-INF/reso
urces, jar:file:///C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/respond/1.4.2/respo
nd-1.4.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/
webjars/datatables/1.10.9/datatables-1.10.9.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file://
/C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/1.11.3/jquery-1.11.3.jar!/META
-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/datatables
-plugins/1.10.9/datatables-plugins-1.10.9.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C
:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bower/bootstrap-wizard/1.0.0/bootstrap-
wizard-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/
org/webjars/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-3.7.3.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file://
/C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/momentjs/2.10.6/momentjs-2.10.6.jar!/
META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/Saufi/.m2/repository/org/webjars/font-a
wesome/4.5.0/font-awesome-4.5.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],STARTING}{file:///D:/VE
DC-TEST/vedc-web/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotati
ons(AnnotationConfiguration.java:574)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(Annot
ationConfiguration.java:444)
    at  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:4
85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1330)
    at   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandle
r.java:772)
    at   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContex
tHandler.java:259)
    at   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:511
)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebApp
Context.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLi
feCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Container
LifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHand
ler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(Con
textHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLi
feCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Container
LifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHand
ler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLi
feCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Container
LifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHand
ler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJ
ettyMojo.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJett
yMojo.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java
:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@49ec6a9f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8088}
[INFO] Started @153457ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Comment: as a quick try, did you try with a larger timeout, say 360?

Comment: It works now. I don't know why it happened last time.anyway, thank you.

Comment: You can reduce scanning jars to improve load speed, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319836/665826)